Java 8 - JAXB: Unmarshalling generics and element with same name
I'm querying several endpoints of an API that returns XML data.
The XML returned by the various endpoints are very similar to each other, with the exception of the name of one element (simplified examples below).
User.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <header>
        <userAPI info="User info"/>
    </header>
    <userAPI>
        <username>charles</username>
    </userAPI>
</root>

Order.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <header>
        <orderAPI info="Order info"/>
    </header>
    <orderAPI>
        <orderId>1</orderId>
    </orderAPI>
</root>

I managed to implement classes using generics but I'm encountering a problem related to elements that have the same name, in fact, a peculiarity of these XMLs is that they always have 2 elements with the same name (one child of header and one child of root):

userAPI for the User.xml file
orderAPI for the Order.xml file

Below are the classes implemented (using Lombok) for unmarshaling the User.xml file
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.30</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

UserApiHeader.java
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "userAPI")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserApiHeader {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String info;
}

UserApi.java
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "userAPI")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserApi {
    @XmlElement
    private String username;
}

Header.java
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "header")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Header<T> {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private T headerDetail;
}

Root.java
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root<T, E> {
    @XmlElement
    private Header<T> header;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private E body;
}

Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n"
                + "<root>\r\n"
                + "    <header>\r\n"
                + "        <userAPI info=\"User info\"/>\r\n"
                + "    </header>\r\n"
                + "    <userAPI>\r\n"
                + "        <username>charles</username>\r\n"
                + "    </userAPI>\r\n"
                + "</root>";
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, UserApi.class, UserApiHeader.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Root<UserApiHeader, UserApi> root = (Root<UserApiHeader, UserApi>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
            System.out.println("Header detail: " + root.getHeader().getHeaderDetail());
            System.out.println("Body:          " + root.getBody());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Result
Header detail: UserApiHeader(info=User info)
Body:          UserApiHeader(info=null)

From the console result you can see that unmarshalling associates the UserApiHeader class with both userAPI elements, therefore it fails to deserialize the root.userAPI element returning null
Another thing I noticed is that if I reverse the orders of the classes when instantiating the JAXBContext, unmarshalling associates the UserApi class with both userAPI, therefore it fails to deserialize the root.header.userAPI element returning null
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, UserApiHeader.class, UserApi.class);
        // ...
    }
}

Header detail: UserApi(username=null)
Body:          UserApi(username=charles)

The problem described does not arise if I change the name of one of the two elements (which, however, I cannot actually do since, as anticipated, they are files that I receive from an API).
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance
UPDATE
I don't know if this can help but, I tried running the marshal with the same classes and the generated xml corresponds to the one I'm trying to deserialize.
Now I'm even more confused
public class Main {
    //...
    
    static void marshal() {
        UserApiHeader userApiHeader = new UserApiHeader();
        userApiHeader.setInfo("User info");
        Header<UserApiHeader> header = new Header<UserApiHeader>();
        header.setHeaderDetail(userApiHeader);
        
        UserApi userApi = new UserApi();
        userApi.setUsername("charles");
        Root<UserApiHeader, UserApi> root = new Root<UserApiHeader, UserApi>();
        root.setHeader(header);
        root.setBody(userApi);
        
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, UserApi.class, UserApiHeader.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);
            String xml = stringWriter.toString();
            System.out.println(xml);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Is it normal that you have @XmlRootElement(name = "userAPI") on public class UserApiHeader. I'd expect to have name = "header"

the UserApiHeader class represents the root.header.userAPI XML element

Yes, I've seen it now. Could you mix the two into only one class ? It'd give UserApi having both @XmlElement username and @XmlAttribute info fields

Unfortunately I can't, in reality, the root.header.userAPI and root.userAPI elements are much more complex

Don't you have a XSD for Order / User objects ?

no, I don't have XSD

One last question : does both userApi in header and in root share the same namespace ?

I actually don't know, I receive the xml as you see it (it simply has extra elements)

Having splitted namespace makes it actually work : <root xmlns:nsh="http://example.com/header"> in root tag, <nsh:userAPI info="User info"/> for header sub object, and @XmlRootElement(name = "userAPI", namespace = "http://example.com/header") as annotation on UserApiHeader class

I couldn't make it work even with your suggestion (maybe I'm doing something wrong) but, in any case, it wouldn't help me anyway since I receive the XMLs as they are
